# Obtaining Index value of dictionary

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I have a piece of code which looks at the following

```
public Test As Dictionary(Of String, String())
```

Which is brought in

```
tester = New Dictionary(Of String, String())
tester.add("Key_EN", {"Option 1_EN", "Option 2_EN", "Option 3_EN"})
tester.add("Key_FR", {"Option 1_FR", "Option 2_FR", "Option 3_FR"})
tester.add("Key_DE", {"Option 1_DE", "Option 2_DE", "Option 3_DE"})
```

There's then a combo box which looks at the following

```
dim Language as string
Language = "_EN" ' note this is done by a drop down combo box to select _EN or _FR etc.
cboTestBox.items.AddRange(tester("Key" & Language))
```

What I need to be able to do is to see what index position the answer is in and convert it back to the Key_EN.

So, for example _DE is selected, then the options of "Option 1_DE", "Option 2_DE", "Option 3_DE" would be displayed.  If they chose Option 3_DE then I need to be able to convert this to Option 3_EN.

Many thanks
Maudise

Answer (score 1):

You can't really get at the index of the dictionary entries and, even if you did, it wouldn't do you much good because you can't use it to access keys or values (I've spent a lot of time trying to get around this to no avail).

The easiest option is to build a reverse lookup dictionary, with the combo key values mapping back to the top-level keys, assuming the combo values are all unique:

```
    Dim oReverseLookup As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    For Each sKey As String In Tester.Keys
        For Each sValue As String In Tester(sKey)
            oReverseLookup.Add(sValue, sKey)
        Next
    Next
```

Then, when your combo value is selected, you can get your original key back:

```
    Dim sSelectedComboValue As String
    sSelectedComboValue = "Option 3_DE"

    If oReverseLookup.ContainsKey(sSelectedComboValue) Then
        ' This will print Key_DE
        Debug.Print("Master Key Value " & oReverseLookup(sSelectedComboValue))
    End If
```

Comment: hmmm, I've just looked at this at work and it's going tor equire some brain power devoted to it.  Thanks, I'll have a look and comment again ion 5 hours

Comment: it's not quite what I'm after, it gets me to Key_DE but it doesn't get me to Option 3_EN which is what I'm after.  I had thought that if I could use a selectedindex type thing then I can hardcode a reference to Key_EN.  What I need the code to do is to return Option 3_EN.  Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: What is the relationship between the values? That they were both at position 3? How do you know you need the EN version and not the FR version (or are you after everything at position 3)?

Comment: they are translations of one another, a simple example (it gets more complex with 9+ options) would be a "Yes", "No", "Maybe" with _FR being "Oui", "Non", "Peut etre" and _DE = "Ja", "Nein", "vielleicht" . The answer needs to be translated to _EN because it is then being imported into a SQL table where I need all the information in English

Answer (score 0):

You could just take the value from the combobox and parse the string. You know that it will contain a `_` before the part you want to change. So just process the string to find the numeric value before `_` and then plug that into another string `Option X_EN` by replacing the `X` or possibly concatenate it with `Option` and `_EN`.

But what you are trying to do seems a really contrived way to go about doing this...

Comment: it's done multiple times and it could be that it is actually "Yes", "No" "Maybe" in "Key_EN" and "Oui", "non", "Peut-etre" in "Key_FR" so I can't use the concatenation or parsing.

Comment: Ah, right, well if the values do not conform to the pattern you mentioned in your question, then this won't work indeed. As mentioned in the other answer by competent tech, the only way would be to map the results back to the original dictionary.